# Changing the color of a fixed-position div while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, frontend

I am experimenting with a very basic layout that has 4 divs, the first and third divs have dark blue backgrounds and the second and fourth have white backgrounds. I have a div in fixed position to the right with a default white color. I need to write some code that if this fixed div is scrolled through the white background divs, it changes its color to black, if it scrolled in the blue, it remains white as it is.

I tinkered for a whole day with getClientBoundingRect() and the IntersectionObserver API and I didn't have any luck.

Here is the code of the basic layout:

```js
        const oddElems = document.querySelectorAll('.oddElem');
        const evenElems = document.querySelectorAll('.evenElem');
        const allElems = document.querySelectorAll('.elem');

        function handleInteresection(entries) {
            entries.forEach(entry => {
                console.log(entry)
            })

        }

        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleInteresection);

        allElems.forEach(elem => {
            observer.observe(elem);
        })
```

```css
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            width: 70%;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .elem {
            border: 2px solid;
        }

        #elem {
            background: #007;
            padding: 20rem;
            color: white;
        }

        #elem2 {
            padding: 20rem;
            background: #fff;
        }

        #elem3 {
            padding: 20rem;
            background: #007;
        }

        #elem4 {
            padding: 20rem;
            background: #fff;
        }


        #flyingbox {
            padding: 2rem;
            width: 2rem;
            left: 80%;
            position: fixed;
            top: 10px;
            background: #fff;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Get Bounding</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="flyingbox">
    </div>
    <div class="elem oddElem" id="elem">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa blanditiis reprehenderit odio, eos
            recusandae ipsam nulla quas sed voluptatum ex neque natus fuga illum dolores. Quis quibusdam odit, unde
            minus?
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="elem evenElem" id="elem2">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa blanditiis reprehenderit odio, eos
            recusandae ipsam nulla quas sed voluptatum ex neque natus fuga illum dolores. Quis quibusdam odit, unde
            minus?
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="elem oddElem" id="elem3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa blanditiis reprehenderit odio, eos
            recusandae ipsam nulla quas sed voluptatum ex neque natus fuga illum dolores. Quis quibusdam odit, unde
            minus?
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="elem evenElem" id="elem4">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa blanditiis reprehenderit odio, eos
            recusandae ipsam nulla quas sed voluptatum ex neque natus fuga illum dolores. Quis quibusdam odit, unde
            minus?
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have any event listener to track the current scroll position. Basically I created an array of each section's offsetTop (distance from parent top) in reverse order, and conditionally check whether window.scrollY (current scroll position) matches an even or odd index.

```js
const allElems = document.querySelectorAll('.elem');
const offsetTops = Array.from(allElems).map(ele => ele.offsetTop).reverse();
const flyingBox = document.getElementById("flyingbox"); 

window.addEventListener("scroll", ()=> {
    const isBlack = offsetTops.findIndex(offsetTop => window.scrollY + 45 > offsetTop)%2 === 0 ? true : false; 
    if(flyingBox.classList.contains("black") && !isBlack) flyingBox.classList.toggle("black");
    if(!flyingBox.classList.contains("black") && isBlack) flyingBox.classList.toggle("black");
});
```

```css
* {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            width: 70%;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .elem {
            border: 2px solid;
        }

        #elem {
            background: #007;
            padding: 20rem;
            color: white;
        }

        #elem2 {
            padding: 20rem;
            background: #fff;
        }

        #elem3 {
            padding: 20rem;
            background: #007;
        }

        #elem4 {
            padding: 20rem;
            background: #fff;
        }


        #flyingbox {
            padding: 2rem;
            width: 2rem;
            left: 80%;
            position: fixed;
            top: 10px;
            background: #fff;
        }
        
        .black {
          background-color: black !important; 
        }
It doesn't look like you have an event listener to retrieve the current scroll position:
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Get Bounding</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="flyingbox">
    </div>
    <div class="elem oddElem" id="elem">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa blanditiis reprehenderit odio, eos
            recusandae ipsam nulla quas sed voluptatum ex neque natus fuga illum dolores. Quis quibusdam odit, unde
            minus?
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="elem evenElem" id="elem2">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa blanditiis reprehenderit odio, eos
            recusandae ipsam nulla quas sed voluptatum ex neque natus fuga illum dolores. Quis quibusdam odit, unde
            minus?
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="elem oddElem" id="elem3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa blanditiis reprehenderit odio, eos
            recusandae ipsam nulla quas sed voluptatum ex neque natus fuga illum dolores. Quis quibusdam odit, unde
            minus?
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="elem evenElem" id="elem4">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa blanditiis reprehenderit odio, eos
            recusandae ipsam nulla quas sed voluptatum ex neque natus fuga illum dolores. Quis quibusdam odit, unde
            minus?
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```